# Has anyone figured out how to program the STWBC-MC module by STM?

Tags: embedded, product, microprocessors, stm8

The documents say that we can flash custom firmware on this module but it doesn't say how. I am unable to locate any build tool chain either. I tried raising a customer support ticket with STM and they don't seem to have any answers. Has anyone used this module in any of their products?

Answer (score 1):

The [User Manual for the STMWB-CM evaluation kit](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00550209-15-w-3coil-fixed-frequency-qicertified-wireless-charger-tx-evaluation-kit-based-on-stwbcmc-stmicroelectronics.pdf) explains the programming process (see section 3.6).  You use an ST-LINK/V2 in-circuit debugger/programmer with single wire interface module (SWIM) and [STVP](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stvp-stm32.html) software.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I missed that tiny note in page 23 of the document. How do I configure the various parameters of the qi wireless charging? I can see that the STM GUI has a ton of parameters to monitor and configure but no document gives me 1. the meaning of each parameter 2. the register addresses to modify. 
I read the other comments about this being confidential information but they (the customer support) aren't saying/admitting that either.

Comment: @GauthamRanganathan That is a separate question best asked in a new question. Also it seems that this chip is meant to be used as an uart end device

Answer (score 0):

It is STM8 and you need IAR workbench for it. I believe that you need to sign NDA first, then (when accepted) you get more detailed documentation and libraries.

[image]

Contact you STM FAE for more details.

Comment: if it is an STM8 internally and I see it has a SWIM pin then no NDA required (you dont sign an NDA for such things normally unless it is broadcom, this is ST) you just use the swim interface as documented (dont even need an stlink).  Granted if you have those things then you can use off the shelf tools.

Comment: @old_timer and what about the another parts of this IC? Can you program them without the documentation? STM8 & SWIM it is the easy part, but far not efficient. Without the SOC documentation built-in STM8 is useless. If they did not publish the data, they decide who and how will get it (if anyone). Maybe theu only do it themself.

Comment: Varies by vendor yes, you found this to be an stm8 so maybe it is not all that secret.  My point is the swim interface does not require special software, special hardware, and an NDA.  Now what addresses you need to touch, sure that may be protected or you may simply need to give up a name, phone number and email address to sales  so they can bug you constantly and then get all the info.  Usually NDA protected materials the name of that thing and how to get it and the fact that exists is not known to the public.  So there is the NDA comment which you can edit out or not use that term.

Comment: contacting an stm fae that is the real answer here.

Comment: Granted this is a product for smartphones and tablets, which means if they have not come to you, then they wont answer you.  if the name on the door isnt apple or samsung or motorola or a short list of others getting a response is unlikely no matter how big or how much money your company has.  not typical for st, but typical for other companies.

Comment: @old_timer if they list only IAR it probably means (knowing the STM) that the SDK is distributed in the IAR library form.  So you can use any toolchain to program the STM8 but it will be rather pointless without the SDK.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the licence terms agreement that ST require you to agree to before accessing document and software downloads?  If so, that is by no definition an NDA; just a regular licence agreement.

Comment: @Clifford anything requiring not public available IP requires NDA. I have signed one, my clients are signing. Not only with ST but most of the silicon vendors start from it. Maybe if you are a $10000000000 business and want to buy for $M they are more flexible.

Comment: @P__J__  That was not my point.  The resources indicated in the image in your question are freely accessible.  I guess I was simply unclear what you were referring to to be clear since old_timer doubted you.  The answer to my question is clearly no, that is not what you were referring to. I think you perhaps misunderstood my question to get quite so animated about it.

Comment: @P__J__  That was not my point.  The resources indicated in the image in your question are freely accessible.  I guess I was simply unclear what you were referring to to be clear since old_timer doubted you.  The answer to my question is clearly no, that is not what you were referring to. I think you perhaps misunderstood my question to get quite so animated about it.